# VFD display programming

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, vfd

I have a VFD display from Soundgraph and I want to know if there are some current
API (C#, JAVA, C++, C, etc.) to program it.

Answer (score 1):

Without the model I can't say more about it, however if it's a text VFD it is very likely based on the [HD44780 Character LCD controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD44780_Character_LCD).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best place for asking questions about a specific device like that. I'd recommend checking out the manufacturer's website to see if they have anything or maybe there's a user's forum where you can find something. If you don't find anything, it might be worth writing your own library and then making it publicly available.

Comment: Yes, I agree but from Soundgraph no answer and so I wanted to know if there were some generic API to program a VFD display!

Answer (score 0):

As it's a text display, it's likely it is HD44780-compatible. For this display driver chip you will find tons of driver software and documentation. If it's equipped with a proprietary controller chip, odd are much worse. Then you would have to check the datasheet for information of the protocol used and then write your own driver SW.